# How To Do Multiprocessing in C without any non-standard libraries

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, opencl

Say you wanted to write your own version of Opencl from scratch in C. How would you go about doing it? How does OpenCL accomplish parallel programming "under the hood"? Is it just pthreads?

Comment: "multiprocessing" is not "multithreading"

Comment: No, it is not. It is utilizing special hardware resources the standard C doesn't know about. If you want to implement it in C you will have to deal with hardware registers and such

Comment: It probably uses embedded assembly code, and is highly non-portable.

Comment: Then how are there libraries that make this portable?

Comment: The most persistent standards are OpenMP, MPI. These are standards. OpenCL is a LOT more than "just pthreads," but its on its way out.

Comment: It is "portable" only to the [supported platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#Version_support) - I.e. the platforms that have the underlying hardware abstraction implemented. Similar to Java - which is "portable" as long as you are porting to a platform with JVM available.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Intel, AMD, ARM, NVIDIA all have CL implementations, available for Windows, Linus, OSX / MacOS, iOS, Android, and embedded Linux on just about every supporting processor. At what point do we stop arguing about semantics?

Comment: @3Dave This is not relevant to the question. The OpenCL is *not* portable to every system which is fully C standard compliant. And this is what the question is about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Of course it isn't. OpenCL isn't C anymore than JavaScript is C. I stand by my relevant statement. One could happily write a CL backend using OpenMP. Or even just plain-old single-threaded C.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) covers much functionality, including a runtime API library, a programming language based on C, a library environment for that language, and likely a loader library for supporting multiple implementations. If you want to look at an open source example of how it could be implemented, [Pocl](http://portablecl.org/), [Clover](https://people.freedesktop.org/~steckdenis/clover/index.html), [Beignet](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/) and [ROCm](https://rocm-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) exist. At least Pocl's CPU target does indeed use pthreads, but OpenCL is designed to support offloading tasks to coprocessors such as GPUs, as well as using vector operations, so one thread does not necessarily run one work item.

The title does not refer to OpenCL, but does request to use "standard" libraries. The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from; for instance, the C standard provides no multithreading and no guarantee of multitasking. Multiprocessing frequently refers to running in multiple processes (in e.g. CPython, this is the only way to get concurrent execution of Python code because of the global interpreter lock). That can be done with the Unix standard function [fork](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/2/fork/). Multithreading can be done using [POSIX threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) (POSIX.1c standard extension) or [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/). Recent versions of OpenMP also support accelerator offloading, which is what OpenCL was designed for. Since OpenMP and OpenCL provide restricted and abstracted environments, they could in principle be implemented on top of many of the others, for instance CUDA.

Implementing parallel execution itself requires hardware knowledge and access, and is typically the domain of the operating system; POSIX threads is often an abstraction layer on this, using e.g. [clone](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) on Linux.

OpenMP is frequently the easiest way to convert a C program to parallel execution, as it is supported by many compilers; you annotate branching points using pragmas and compile with e.g. -fopenmp for GCC. Such programs will still work as before if compiled without OpenMP.

Comment: Nice answer. But, "Multiprocessing frequently refers to running in multiple processes" is pretty platform-specific. It's just as common (and becoming moreso) to fire off a bunch of threads or a kernel within a single process to parallelize a processor-intensive task within a single process.

Comment: And that's the primary domain of OpenMP, while multiprocessing is the primary domain of MPI (including across multiple computers; implementations include e.g. MPIch and OpenMPI). The borders keep on shifting though.

Comment: well put! (more characters here.)

Answer (score 1):

First off: OpenCL != parallel processing. That is one of its strengths, but there's a lot more to it.

Focusing on one part of your question:

> Say you wanted to write your own version of Opencl from scratch in C.

For one: get familiar with driver development. Our GPU CL runtime is pretty intimately involved with the drivers. If you want to start from scratch, you're going to need to get very familiar with the PCIe protocols and dig up some memories about toggling pins. This is doable, but it exemplifies "nontrivial."

Multithreading at the CPU level is an entirely different matter that's been documented out the yin-yang. The great thing about using an OS that you didn't have to write yourself is that this is already handled for you.

> Is it just pthreads?

How do you think those are implemented? Their functionality is part of the spec, but their implementation is entirely platform-dependent, which you may call "non standard." The underlying implementation of a thread depends on the OS (if there is one, which is not a given), compiler, and a ton of other factors.

This is a great question.